# Update eclipse editor references

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing refactor action for my custom eclipse editor. When the file is renamed, I reset the editor input based on the renamed file and also update the part name.

However the editor references still hold the previous input and file names. Thus eclipse does not know changes to the editor window and cause problems later on like "empty editor tab" exceptions.

How to update the editor references for refactor actions on eclipse editor?

Answer (score 1):

In your class derived from `EditorPart` do something like:

```java
IEditorInput input = ... new editor input

setInputWithNotify(input);

setPartName(input.getName());

firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY);
```

Comment: I have a `MultiPageEditorPart` and I tried the above code with the main editor and also the sub editor tabs. 

However the editor reference still points to the previous file location.

Comment: The editor reference just gets the input directly from the editor so I can't see how this can not work.